# php page to be included in joomla

Tags: joomla

I have written a php page that is getting data from a database and graph it via highcharts javascript.

I would like now to be able to put that in joomla and then use the username from joomla to graph the specific data from that user.

How can I do that?

Thanks for your help,

John.

Comment: Have you considered turning your PHP script/page into a Joomla extension? depending on the complexity of the script, you might want to consider using a Plugin such as Sourcerer or maybe even Jumi

Comment: Does it take time to create a joomla extension and do you have access to info like username and other parameters? I could spend time to create an extension but I m wondering if it is heavy or not.

Comment: It will take as much time as needed. There is a lot of documentation on the Joomla Docs to help you, and yes, you do have access to things like usernames etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an iFrame Wrapper menu item whenever you want to include a page that isn't part of your Joomla website.